# spring app Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.proper

Tags: java, spring, maven, intellij-idea

**errors**

o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\user.m2\repository\net\openhft\chronicle-queue\5.20.123\chronicle-queue-5.20.123.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/chronicle-core-2.20.126.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/chronicle-analytics-2.20.5.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/annotations-19.0.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/chronicle-bytes-2.20.111.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/chronicle-wire-2.20.117.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/compiler-2.4.1.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/chronicle-threads-2.20.111.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/affinity-3.20.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/jna-5.5.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/jna-platform-5.5.0.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/jlbh-1.19.30.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/commons-cli-1.4.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-queue/5.20.123/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar
2022-09-14 03:54:52.093  INFO 3440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls    : The Class-Path manifest attribute in C:\Users\user.m2\repository\net\openhft\chronicle-bytes\2.20.111\chronicle-bytes-2.20.111.jar referenced one or more files that do not exist: file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-bytes/2.20.111/chronicle-core-2.20.125.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-bytes/2.20.111/chronicle-analytics-2.20.5.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-bytes/2.20.111/slf4j-api-1.7.30.jar,file:/C:/Users/user/.m2/repository/net/openhft/chronicle-bytes/2.20.111/annotations-19.0.0.jar
2022-09-14 03:54:53.404 ERROR 3440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration.propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:144) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:120) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:332) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:237) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:755) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:402) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at mycrm.Application.main(Application.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:648) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1614) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.collectBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:238) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:231) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getBeanNamesForType(OnBeanCondition.java:221) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchingBeans(OnBeanCondition.java:169) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:144) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2536) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted

2022-09-14 03:54:53.434  WARN 3440 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Unable to close ApplicationContext

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration] from ClassLoader [jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader@73d16e93]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:481) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:358) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:414) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.lambda$getTypeForFactoryMethod$2(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:742) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:741) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:680) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:648) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1614) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1243) ~[spring-context-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:890) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:878) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:865) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:803) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1247) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1236) ~[spring-boot-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
    at mycrm.Application.main(Application.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.3.12.RELEASE.jar:2.3.12.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3434) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2536) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:463) ~[spring-core-5.2.15.RELEASE.jar:5.2.15.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
    ... 28 common frames omitted

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.897 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-09-14T03:54:53+03:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```

some errors that i got
I think i got dependency failure

Comment: Please add more detail to your issue, including how you have attempted to solve it and only include relevant code

Comment: That's not a proper question. You just dumped a screen full of errors on us. Please read how to ask a proper question.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mycrm</groupId>
    <!--то куда компилится в таргет-->
    <artifactId>MyBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<!--        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--       /////////////////////////// <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>-->
    </parent>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>nickolay3n</id>
            <name>Nikolay </name>
            <email>**@gmail.com</email>
            <properties>
                <active>true</active>
            </properties>
        </developer>
    </developers>


    <name>crm-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<!--        <tomcat.version>8.5.5</tomcat.version>-->
<!--        <spring.boot.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>-->

        <spring.boot.version>2.3.12.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <!-- Spring will find the version compatible with the parent -->
        </dependency>
        <!--Это шаблонизатор для HTML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--Это шаблонизатор для HTML конец-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
            <!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataBase support
        //Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
<!--            <version>3.1.0</version>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version> 5.0.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- security for login-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
            <!--            <exclusions>-->
            <!--                <exclusion>-->
            <!--                    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>-->
            <!--                    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>-->
            <!--                </exclusion>-->
            <!--            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.3</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
            <scope>compile</scope>
<!--            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0-M17</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--        <resources>-->
        <!--            <resource>-->
        <!--                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>-->
        <!--                <filtering>true</filtering>-->
        <!--            </resource>-->
        <!--        </resources>-->


        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>-->
            <!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--                <version>2.4</version>-->
            <!--                <configuration>-->
            <!--                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>-->
            <!--                    &lt;!&ndash;<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--                </configuration>-->
            <!--            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <!--                <dependencies>-->
                <!--                    <dependency>-->
                <!--                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>-->
                <!--                        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>-->
                <!--                        <version>1.3</version>-->
                <!--                    </dependency>-->
                <!--                </dependencies>-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version> 3.3.2</version>
                <!--                <version>4.0.0</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--<plugins>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugins>-->
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.org</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>proselyte.lib1</id>
            <url>http://download.proselyte.net/maven2/lib1</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>proselyte.lib2</id>
            <url>http://download.proselyte.net/maven2/lib2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>https</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>https</id>
            <url>file://C:\Users\User\.m2\repository</url>
<!--            <url>D:\server\maven\repository</url>-->
        </repository>


    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>-->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

**solved this by own. the problem was in dependecies of course**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>mycrm</groupId>
    <!--то куда компилится в таргет-->
    <artifactId>MyBase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
<!--        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>-->
<!--       /////////////////////////// <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>-->
    </parent>

    <developers>
        <developer>
            <id>nickolay3n</id>
            <name>Nikolay </name>
            <email>nic***n@gmail.com</email>
            <properties>
                <active>true</active>
            </properties>
        </developer>
    </developers>


    <name>crm-complete</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
<!--        <tomcat.version>8.5.5</tomcat.version>-->
<!--        <spring.boot.version>2.0.9.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>-->

        <spring.boot.version>2.3.12.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.boot.dependencies.scope>compile</spring.boot.dependencies.scope>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <!-- Spring will find the version compatible with the parent -->
        </dependency>
        <!--Это шаблонизатор для HTML-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mustache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--Это шаблонизатор для HTML конец-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
<!--            <scope>runtime</scope>-->
            <!--            <optional>true</optional>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DataBase support
        //Error creating bean with name 'jpaMappingContext': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
        At least one JPA metamodel must be present!
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId> org.apache.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-build-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
<!--            <version>3.0.1</version>-->
<!--            <version>2.5</version>-->

<!--            <version>3.1.0</version>-->
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
            <artifactId>plexus-compiler-javac</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- security for login-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
            <!--            <exclusions>-->
            <!--                <exclusion>-->
            <!--                    <groupId>aopalliance</groupId>-->
            <!--                    <artifactId>aopalliance</artifactId>-->
            <!--                </exclusion>-->
            <!--            </exclusions>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0</version>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.3.12.RELEASE</version>-->
            <version>2.6.11</version>
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--            <scope>${spring.boot.dependencies.scope}</scope>-->
<!--            <scope>compile</scope>-->
<!--            <version>2.0.9.RELEASE</version>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.65</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <!--        <resources>-->
        <!--            <resource>-->
        <!--                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>-->
        <!--                <filtering>true</filtering>-->
        <!--            </resource>-->
        <!--        </resources>-->


        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <!--            <plugin>-->
            <!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>-->
            <!--                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>-->
            <!--                <version>2.4</version>-->
            <!--                <configuration>-->
            <!--                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>-->
            <!--                    &lt;!&ndash;<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--                </configuration>-->
            <!--            </plugin>-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <!--                <dependencies>-->
                <!--                    <dependency>-->
                <!--                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.shared</groupId>-->
                <!--                        <artifactId>maven-filtering</artifactId>-->
                <!--                        <version>1.3</version>-->
                <!--                    </dependency>-->
                <!--                </dependencies>-->
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version> 3.3.2</version>
                <!--                <version>4.0.0</version>-->
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <!--<plugins>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
        </plugins>-->
    </build>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven.org</id>
            <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>proselyte.lib1</id>
            <url>http://download.proselyte.net/maven2/lib1</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>proselyte.lib2</id>
            <url>http://download.proselyte.net/maven2/lib2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>https</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        </repository>


    </repositories>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>https</id>
            <url>file://C:\Users\User\.m2\repository</url>
<!--            <url>D:\server\maven\repository</url>-->
        </repository>


    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--<dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>-->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: More detail please. What was it in the dependencies that you found?